# find out missing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have 2 databases one in local and another in clould , need to synchronise stored procedure from local to online. now problem is there are few newer stored procedures in local and i need to migrate them to online , there are 500+ prcedures. Is there any query to find out the procedures  which is in local but at online , i cannot overwrite all procedures from local to online because procedure which are already at online are updated

I have backed up online database to my local as well . its name is db2

assuming my existing local database is db1 , i need to findout procedures which are at locak but not at online

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that

```
SELECT p1.name, p2.name
FROM db1.sys.procedures p1
full outer join db2.sys.procedures p2 on p1.name = p2.name
where p1.name is null or p2.name is null
```

It gives you all procedures names that are not in both DBs.

Comment: +1 his/her requirement is to find out procedure which is in db1 but not in db2, this will find out the procedures which is in db2 and not in db1 also..

Comment: i need only those one which are not online but are at local, there could be some newer procdures at online also, anyway thankyou for your effort